# How do I change the Wi-Fi hotspot channel?

Tags: wi-fi, wifi-hotspot

Is it possibe to change the channel my phone broadcasts its Wi-Fi hotspot on?

Right now it's using the same channel as my neighbour (6). My router is reporting several unused slots.

Answer (score 4):

If you're referring to the one built into Froyo (and I assume Gingerbread), when you're creating your hostspot hit the Menu button and you'll see Advanced options. In there you can select the channel.

Answer (score 4):

I'm reasonably sure that you cannot change the WiFi hotspot channel without firmware modification in standard Android Gingerbread.

I have an Nexus One (Android version 2.3.6) and I have not found any advanced menu accessible from the menu button and I've tried hitting the menu button to no avail in every WiFi tethering page. I've only been able to change SSID, Key & Security mode.